# What standards or industry guidance define a top temperature for human contact to surfaces?

Tags: temperature, safety

I'm looking for guidance to define how hot is too hot when related to human safety.  I have heard of a general limit from OSAH of 60 °C (140 °F) being ok for contact up to 5 sec.  Are there better sources for defining this limit for different temperatures and time limits?

Comment: Practically speaking, it will depend a lot on the thermal conductivity of the material. A hot aluminum plate will burn you much faster than a hot wood surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a safety issue, you'll need to carefully follow relevant standards such as:

- [ASTM C1055-20](https://www.astm.org/c1055-20.html): Standard Guide for Heated System Surface Conditions that Produce Contact Burn Injuries.
- [ISO 13732-1:2006](https://www.iso.org/standard/43558.html) Ergonomics of the thermal environment — Methods for the assessment of human responses to contact with surfaces — Part 1: Hot surfaces

These can be traced back to a seminal series of papers in 1947 on ["Studies of Thermal Injury"](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=%22Studies+of+Thermal+Injury%22+%22Moritz%22+%22american+journal+of+pathology%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=1947&as_yhi=1947) by Moritz and Henriques. [Figure 1 in an 1963 article](https://pmj.bmj.com/content/39/458/717) by J.P. Bull in the British Medical Journal summarizes their temperature-time threshold curve for injury and you can see where the "60°C for 5 seconds" threshold criterion for partial thickness burns comes from. According to the figure, the damage takes only about 1 second at 65°C,  and about 100 seconds at 50°C.

For a more recent review, check out the 2017 article ["A review of the evidence for threshold of burn injury"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.burns.2017.04.003) by Martin and Falder in the journal *Burns*. According to that article, burn injury occurs when the basal epidermis reaches 44°C and the rate of tissue damage increases logarithmically with temperature, until by 70°C the damage is so rapid that "interpretation can be difficult".  This is roughly consistent with the figure mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

EN 60335-2 family of regulations addresses this issue. Tough read though. Possibly interesting source of information: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiUgvDF3rP7AhUpgP0HHZSWCu8QFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fec.europa.eu%2Fdocsroom%2Fdocuments%2F5263%2Fattachments%2F1%2Ftranslations%2Fen%2Frenditions%2Fnative&usg=AOvVaw3ukF_Rq6zm0vu-DHNuQtpA

Non-functional hot surfaces project.